# TypeError: $http.movie is not a function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I´m trying to save a movie title to my database using Angular and Rails, but I´m getting some errors, and I think I know what the problem is, but I don´t know how to fix it.

The setup,

This is my search template. When a user clicks on the `addMovie` div the `addMovieCtrl` fires and tries to save the input.

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "searchCtrl", :id => "container_search"}
  #addMovie{"ng-controller" => "addMovieCtrl"}
    %div{"ng-click" => "addMovie()"}
      %input{:type => "text", "ng-model" => "title"}
      addMovie action.
```

This is the movieController.js,

```
angular.module('addMovieseat', ['ui.router', 'templates'])

  .controller('addMovieCtrl', ['$scope', 'movies',
    function($scope, movies){
      $scope.movies = movies.movies;

      $scope.addMovie = function(){

        console.log ("Hello")

        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        movies.create({
          titles: $scope.title,
        });
        $scope.title = 'Star wars';
      };
    }
  ])
```

And this is the movieService.js

```
angular.module('addMovieseat')

  .factory('movies', ['$http', function($http){
    var o = {
      movies: []
    };

    o.create = function(movie){
      return $http.movie('/movies.json', movie).success(function(data){
        o.movies.push(data);
      });
    };

    return o;

  }])
```

The movie.rb model in Rails

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base

  def as_json(options = {})
  end

end
```

my app.js.coffee,

```
@myApp        = angular.module('myApp',[]);
@flapperNews  = angular.module('flapperNews',[]);
@app          = angular.module('movieseat', ['addMovieseat','myApp', 'flapperNews', 'ui.router', 'Devise']);

# for compatibility with Rails CSRF protection

@app.config([
  '$httpProvider', ($httpProvider)->
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-Token'] = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')
])

@app.run(->
  console.log 'angular app running'
)
```

When I click on the `addMovie` div I get this error,

`TypeError: $http.movie is not a function
    at Object.o.create`

I've folled the Angular/Rails tutorial on thinkster.io and something I've noticed is that when I go to `localhost:3000/posts.json` I get a page with all the posts I've created (during the tutorial). But when I go the `localhost:3000/movies.json` I get a `No route matches [GET] "/movies.json"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course its not.

Replace

```
$http.movie('/movies.json', movie)
```

With:

```
$http.post('/movies.json', movie)
```

---

Sidenote, haml lets you write nice html props like:

```
%div( ng-click="addMovie()" )
```

Comment: Makes sence, I just replaced all post with movies. A dumb move (still learning). Thanks.

Comment: I've got another question relating to this problem. I've stated that I can't acces `localhost:3000/movies.json` I've read the thinkster tutorial again but can't see where the proces of creating that file is. I do have a `localhost:3000/posts.json` but can't figure out how to create this for the movies.json.

Comment: you need routes `resources :movies`, and a controller

Comment: Excellent, it's been a while since I did some Rails work. But it's comming back. Thank you for the tips.